# How to deserialize XML element with package name using Xstream?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xstream

I have an xml response and trying to convert it to java object using Xstream library.

```
<products>
   <com.example.model.ProductModel>
     <productDefinition>
       <productId>1</productId>
       <productType>ASD</productType>
       <price>10</price>
     </productDefinition>
   </com.example.model.ProductModel>
 </products>
```

Here are my java classes for this:

```
@XStreamAlias("products")
public class Product {

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="com.example.model.ProductModel")
    private ProductModel productModel;

    //getters, setters
}

public class ProductModel {

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="productDefinition")
    private ProductDefinition productDefinition;

    //getters, setters
}
```

When I convert this xml to java object, Product object is not null, but the ProductModel inside of it becomes null. I guess the problem is about the full package name of the xml tag. Any suggestions about how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion, XStream `aliasField` method helped me solve it.

```
xstream.aliasField("com.example.model.ProductModel", Product.class, "productModel");
```

This simply means, map the `"com.example.model.ProductModel"` element in the xml to `productModel` object of `Product` class.